# Get rid of FindBugs rules with javasonar squid rules. What about rejected rules?

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

We want to replace all our FindBugs rules with squid rules to improve performance.
For that we use the mapping shown in [SonarQube Java Plugin coverage/deprecation of FindBugs](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/findbugs.html).

But many of our FindBugs rules are listed as Rejected FindBugs rules e.g. AM_CREATES_EMPTY_JAR_FILE_ENTRY or EQ_UNUSUAL.

Why are they rejected and how could we replace them?

Comment: Any chance to update the link that points to the mapping of FindBugs to Sonar Squid rules? Seems like it just points to the sonarsource landing page these days...